# Method Error 'Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' from await and async properties

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have installed the NuGet Package Async for .NET Framework 4, Silverlight 4 and 5, and Windows Phone 7.5 and 8.

```
Version 1.0.16
```

I am using Microsoft .NET 4.0 and I can not upgrade due to Web Hosting Package Restrictions. (Sadly!)

My test Code: (I am doing a Linq to SQL Query in place of Thread.Sleep)

```
public class Search
{
public async Task<List<Result>> GetResults(string SearchString)
{
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
}
}
```

My Error:

```
Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx talks about the error but it is not really the answer as I am not using VB and I am already doing what the solution describes.

**[EDIT]**
I am getting a warning:

```
Warning 4   The primary reference "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awaiting a sleep is still going to be consuming the time of a thread pool thread.  If you don't have the tools for properly asynchronous operations you're probably better of just using entirely synchronous methods instead of using async over sync.

Comment: This is a test method and not the actual method I am using. I am running a SQL Link Query in place of the sleep.

Comment: Is this a web application?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What a Nightmare! I have found the problem.

```
Microsoft.Bcl
```

It appears in my case that the Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Async are in conflict. I removed the Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Async with the following commands:

```
uninstall-package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -force
```

then:

```
uninstall-package Microsoft.Bcl -force
```

and then install again:

```
install-package Microsoft.Bcl.Async
```

Now it works a charm. I cant believe this? Also not sure as to why Microsoft.Bcl was left there in the first place. After removing Microsoft.Bcl.Async it gets left behind. So far all works fine. Some more testing to be done.

If others have issues with NuGet Packages, you can try at your own risk:

```
update-package -pre
```

This will try to roll back packages that have been updated. This is how I found the issue.

**[EDIT]**
Its worth noting after further testing, Microsoft.Bcl is not removed when one uninstalls Microsoft.Bcl.Async. Microsoft.Bcl can be updated separately and it appears this update outside Microsoft.Bcl.Async may be an issue. Microsoft.Bcl is installed when one installs Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

Hope this helps others!

Comment: Awesome -- I would not have thought it was a package issue.  Not sure if I had partial packages or if I never installed them at all, but I got errors for the uninstall, and the install worked fine, and the error was just gone..  I'll try to connect the dots later!

Answer (score 2):

Modify your configuration as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-[version]" newVersion="[version]" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-[version]" newVersion="[version]" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Replacing [version] with the version (for example, 2.5.10.0) of `System.Runtime` and `System.Threading.Tasks` that you are referencing.

Comment: When you installed the nugget package, did those lines come with it? If so, remove the `<dependentAssembly>` parts.

Comment: I have removed and reinstalled and it appears so, Yes they do.