# I can't await awaitable?

Tags: c#, async-await

Visual Studio complains on the following:

```
public RelayCommand SendRegistrationCommand { get; private set; }
public async void SendRegistration()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("url");

    // ... todo
}

Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>'
```

I thought I've done this before, GetStringAsync is not awaitable?

Comment: Can you show us full method? Maybe it is not marked by `async` modifier?

Comment: @tpeczek ive posted the function

Comment: You're probably targeting .NET 4.0. Can you switch to 4.5?

Comment: GetStringAsync is awaitable. What kind of application are you building? You may be missing a reference, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439564/method-error-cannot-await-system-threading-tasks-task-from-await-and-async-pr

Comment: @Oskar Lindberg im build a WP8 app with portable class library

Comment: if you are already targeting 4.5 or higher then `Uninstall-Package Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack` may fix it as it did for me

Answer (score 20):

You're probably targeting .NET 4.0.

If you can, switch to .NET 4.5 which supports async/await semantics.

<strike>If you can't, consider using the Async Targeting Pack: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack</strike>

**Edit**

As per the comments, `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` should be used instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Comment: My portable class library is targeting .NET 4.5 :-/

Comment: `AsyncTargetingPack` is quite old; `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` is the correct package to use.

Comment: @Jason94: `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` is required if you want to use `async` from within a portable class library.

Answer (score -3):

Ensure that client.GetStringAsync("url") is an async Task

```
private async Task GetStringAsync(string str)
{
}
```

Comment: GetStringAsync doesn't need to be async. It just needs to return Task