# async await for a HttpClient.PostAsync call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to wrap a call to PostAsync so I don't have to recode the call sequence all over my code base.  The issue I'm having is the HttpResponseMessage I assigned from the call is not the same as the one the consumer of my method calls.  Here is the code:

```
internal class RestHttpClient
{
    public HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

    public async void SendRequest(string adaptiveUri, string xmlRequest)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            StringContent httpConent = new StringContent(xmlRequest, Encoding.UTF8);

            try
            {
                ResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(adaptiveUri, httpConent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                ResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to call the method as follows:

```
RestHttpClient restHttpClient = new RestHttpClient();

restHttpClient.SendRequest(adaptiveUri, xmlRequest);

return restHttpClient.ResponseMessage;
```

When I make the call the ResponseMessage object always contains an Ok status even if that is not what is actually returned from the PostAsync call.

Comment: @Alexei This isn't a duplicate. That question doesn't answer the OP's problem at all

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov based on the title it should... but it does not... removed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this is because your method is `async void` which executes in a "fire and forget" fashion, so you're seeing the value returned by the instansiation of the response message, not the response of `PostAsync`.

Don't expose a single class `HttpResponseMessage` field, it may be stale if called concurrently on the same instance. Instead, return a new instance each time:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync(string adaptiveUri, string xmlRequest)
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        StringContent httpConent = new StringContent(xmlRequest, Encoding.UTF8);

        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
        try
        {
             responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(adaptiveUri, httpConent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (responseMessage == null)
            { 
                responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            }
            responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", ex);
        }
        return responseMessage;
    }
}
```

And when you invoke it, properly `await` it:

```
return await restHttpClient.SendRequestAsync(adaptiveUri, xmlRequest);
```

Comment: You know that it should be duplicate of some existing answer by Stephen Cleary ... But I agree that duplicates are not showing enough love to OP.

Comment: It seems to work.. a little but the result I'm seeing from the call is:

response Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}" System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>

My UI just sits there for a moment and I don't get the actual response from the service call.

Comment: Where are you seeing that?

Comment: My mistake, I modified the caller to the send method to use async..await but the change didn't stick.  After I put it back in the UI was responsive and the call completed.

Thanks!

Comment: I try it in .Net Framework 4.0 but it seems its not working.., `Type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> is not awaitable`

Comment: @janmvtrinidad - See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439564/method-error-cannot-await-system-threading-tasks-task-from-await-and-async-pr) thread

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks for this link, its also works for me to use async await in .Net Framework 4.0.,.

Comment: I've been trying to find out why my await async calls weren't working for a while. Your last tip, to also await the invocation, fixed it for me!